# How to handle the keyboard not present issue in iOS automation

Tags: appium-ios

I am writing the script to automate a mobile app on iOS and even since the iOS version upgraded to 14, I’ve seen this error. I even tried to invoke the keyboard by clicking on the text entry field first but that didn’t help. Any suggestions on how to handle this or anyone handled this in Appium?

Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys}

Thanks,
Nus